# Constructing a UNIX pipeline that finds all files in a directory (using find ,xargs and du commands )

Tags: linux, unix, embedded-linux, unix-timestamp

I need to construct a UNIX pipeline that finds all files under the directory containing the word "english" (using find command)and calculate the size of each and sort them .
This is my implementation and I am getting an assertion error, any inputs will be appreciated

```
find /usr/share/dict -type f -name "english*"| xargs -n 1 du | sort -n
```

The error message is

```
E           AssertionError: assert 44 == 2
E        +  where 44 = len(['4\t./.git/branches\r', '4\t./.git/objects/info\r', '4\t./.git/objects/pack\r', '4\t./.git/refs/tags\r', '8\t./.cache/v/cache\r', '8\t./.git/info\r', ...])
```

Comment: "getting an assertion error". Interesting. Please update your Q to show the exact text of the error message. (Don't make us guess ;-), OK?). Good luck.

Comment: i have updated the error message.

Comment: hard to understand how `du`, `xargs` or `sort` are generating that message. Try removing elements from the right of the pipeline (i.e first `sort`, then `du`) and hide the std-out output, ie. `> /dev/null`. Let us know which program is generating that message. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two error:

1. Files can contain "spaces" - user print0
2. It's must be files. Use -type f

`find /usr/share/dict -type f -name "english*" -print0| xargs -0 du | sort -n`